# How do you check a condition of several pandas DataFrame.Series element-wise and apply the result to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.Dataframe.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([(11,12,13),(1,3,5),(1,1,2)], columns=['a','b','c'])

    a   b   c
0  11  12  13
1   1   3   5
2   3   1   2
```

I would like to create a fourth column called `d` which would tell me if each element in a row is bigger than 10. It this example it would look like this.

```
    a   b   c      d
0  11  12  13   True
1   1   3   5  False
2   3   1   2  False
```

I tried this which gives me a TypeError.

```
x = df['a']
y = df['b']
z = df['c']
df['d'] = df.apply(lambda x,y,z: True if x > 10 and y > 10 and z > 10 else False)
```

I have also tried this which gives me a ValueError.

```
df['d'] = True
df['e'] = df['d'].where(df['a'] > 10 and df['b'] > 10 and df['c'] > 10, other=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use `np.all` on the expression `df > 10`:

```
In [423]:

df['d'] = np.all(df > 10, axis=1)
df
Out[423]:
    a   b   c      d
0  11  12  13   True
1   1   3   5  False
2   1   1   2  False

In [421]:

df > 10
Out[421]:
       a      b      c
0   True   True   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
In [422]:

np.all(df > 10, axis=1)
Out[422]:
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: I would like to check whether each element from each column is higher than 10, not whether the sum of all of them is higher than 10.